# Can't apply filter [ME] to person field updated by CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom

I create calendar item and add user field value by SharePoint CSOM. Item successfully created but I can't apply [ME] filter to person field. Returned no results. But if I open item to edit and save without edit, filter works and returns correct result. Why I can't apply [ME] filter?

I use this code to create item:

```
FieldUserValue userValue = new FieldUserValue();
User userIdSp = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(@"domain\User");
ctx.Load(userIdSp);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItemCreate = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItemCreate["EventDate"] = leave.BegDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
oListItemCreate["EndDate"] = leave.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
oListItemCreate["Employee"] = userValue.LookupId;
oListItemCreate["EmployeeStr"] = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", person.LastName, person.FirstName, person.Patronymic);         

oListItemCreate.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Please have a look here for how to set a user field https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/11/30/setting-a-sharepoint-person-or-group-field-value-with-csom/

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thank you! I add prefix to `User userIdSp = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(@"i:0#.w|domain\User");` and all work fine!